# Problem in my final solution of a proof regarding inequalities

Tags: real-analysis

We are given the following problem. Assume that

$\epsilon < \int_0^1 f(x)dx < \epsilon$ and $-\epsilon < f'(x) < \epsilon  $   for all $x \in [0,1]$

Now show that this leads to

$f(0) - \epsilon x \leq f(x) \leq f(0) + \epsilon x$ for all $x \in [0,1]$

My work:
$-\epsilon < f'(x) < \epsilon  $

$\implies -\int_0^x\epsilon dx < \int_0^x f'(x)dx<\int_0^x\epsilon dx$

$\implies -\epsilon x < f(x)-f(0) < \epsilon x$
 and thus

$f(0)-\epsilon x < f(x) < f(0)+\epsilon x$

Now, it is clear that I found f(x) to be strictly less or greater than something instead of less/greater or equal. It is also clear that the equality part needs to be there, since $x=0$ would yield an equality. Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Strict inequality holds if $f'$ is continuous i.e. if $f$ is continuously differentiable. Otherwise equality may occur due to limiting argument.

Comment: What do you mean by saying $\epsilon < \int_0^1 f < \epsilon$?

Comment: Context of the question: The two parts which satisfy being less than epsilon are part of a norm. This is a subquestion